# How to store all the numbers in one variable called numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I decided to make a calculator so I need to add numbers to other numbers so numbers must be a variable how can I store all the integer and float numbers into only one variable.

Comment: Make it a list?! I'd strongly recommend a basic tutorial.

Comment: Have you learned about lists? You'd store the numbers in a list.

Comment: More context is needed, such as how are you getting these numbers, how are you planning to operate on them... But yeah, the answer is probably a list...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a list. Here is an example.

```
number_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def addition(number_list):
    result = 0
    for number in number_list:  # the for loop will iterate every number of your list one by one
        result += number  # Which does the same as result = result + number
    return result

# if you want to see the result in the terminal, you can print the result with:
print(addition(number_list))
```